# MySQL Connector/Net EF Database First Spatial Datatypes

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, spatial, connector-net

Using:

- Entity Framework 5
- MySQL Connector Net 6.8.4
- MySQL 5.6.21
- Visual Studio 2013
- MySQL Workbench 6.2

Created the following table in MySQL using the workbench
[image: MySQL table, five columns of types int as pk, linestring, polygon, double, geometry]

Opened my application in Visual Studio 2013, navigated to my data access layer project, opened the .edmx, right-clicked on the canvas and chose 
"Update model from database...".
I proceeded to add the new table, clicked finish, and this is what got spit out:

[image: Route Geometry db model table with not the correct properties]
[image: Redundant picture of auto-generated model class]

As you can see all the spatial data types were just ignored.

The Data Access project include (among other things) the following references:

- EntityFramework
- MySql.Data
- MySql.Data.Entity.EF5
- MySql.Web
- System.Data.Entity

I realize that in EF they'll be of type DbGeometry, but I feel like the update process should be able to figure this out for itself. And while I could manually add the mappings, I would prefer not to since they would get blown away next time someone runs the "Update model from database..."

Any insights or suggestions? Thanks!

**Edit:**
Tested with Entity Framework 6 and continued to have the issue

Comment: Any reason why you are not using EF6?

Comment: There was a compatibility issue I was having with EF6 and ConnectorNet, I forget what exactly though.. I'll see if I can find the old emails.

Comment: @Eniola Compatibility issue with EF6 and ConnectorNet with the default scaffolded CRUD methods that creating a .NET MVC Controller generates... running them results in a SQL Syntax Error

Comment: @Eniola tested with EF6, did not resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the Error List Warnings after attempting an "Update Model from Database" I now see:

> Error 6005: The data type 'geometry' is currently not supported for the target Entity Framework version; the column 'test_geometry' in the table 'def.spatialdb.routegeometry' was excluded.

This is using latest Entity Framework 6, so I guess it's not possible using code-first only.

Possible solution would be to edit the auto-generated classes to add the DBGeometry properties, but those would get blown away every time the model is updated.

Comment: Have you got any other solution for this issue? Because, I'm also facing the same problem with EF 6. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @VishwajeetKulkarni not yet, my update here is the result of a bug in Connector/Net. My current work around is in MySQL I store both the spatial data type and the geometry's Well Known Text in the table.
For most spatial operations I use Stored Procedures in MySQL and call them through EF. For any time I need to manipulate a geometry, I retrieve the Well Known Text and instantiate the geometry using NetTopologySuite and GeoAPI for .Net